# How to set a vector child of an object so x , y and z are local

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

Here is the point, I have to create a raycast system that follows the camera.
Due to a specific inteface on screen I cannot use the ScreenPointToRay() method provided by Unity.

But here is how I try to do the thing:

- I get my mouse coordinates between -1 and 1 in both axes
- I want to add these coordinates as a Vector3 to the camera.transform.forward as a normal vector
- the sum of both rays should give me the final one.

But for some reasons, It appears that the final coordinates aren't really local and I experience some issues with one of the coordinate depending on where I look

I tried to make the vector local using multiple ways provided by Unity :

- Vector3.Cross
- cam.transform.worldToLocalMatrix.MultiplyVector
- cam.transform.InverseTransformVector

but in vain

```cs
            //Vector form mouse coordinates
            aim = new Vector3(mousePosInGameScreen.x ,mousePosInGameScreen.y,0);
            // Try to make it global first
            aim = transform.TransformVector(aim);

            //Tried to do a Cross multiplication with the camera.transform.forward vector
            //Vector3 aim = Vector3.Cross(cam.transform.forward,new Vector3(mousePosInGameScreen.x,mousePosInGameScreen.y,1));

            //Tried to set it to the local matrix using worldToLocalMatrix
            //aim = cam.transform.worldToLocalMatrix.MultiplyVector(aim);

            //Does pretty much the same but with simpler method
            aim = cam.transform.InverseTransformVector(aim);

            //Adding this to cam.transform.forward
            Vector3 direction = aim /*/ coefDirection*/ + cam.transform.forward;


            Ray forwardRay = new Ray(cam.transform.position, rotation);//forward
            Ray aimRay = new Ray(cam.transform.position + rotation, aim/4);//aim
            Ray finalRay = new Ray(cam.transform.position, direction);//Final Ray

            Debug.DrawRay(finalRay.origin, finalRay.direction, Color.green);
            Debug.DrawRay(forwardRay.origin, forwardRay.direction, Color.red);
            Debug.DrawRay(aimRay.origin, aimRay.direction, Color.yellow);
```

I expected to have a nice right-angled triangle like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG3Zi.png

I sometimes got weird angles when looking in some directions.
It's always fine when I look forward, but when I look backwards( for example ), The "x" aim coordinate is inverted

So if someone knows what's going on here I take it and thanks by advance

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about why you can't use `ScreenPointToRay()`?

Comment: Can you use `cam.ScreenPointToRay(Vector3.Scale(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth-1, cam.pixelHeight-1, 0f), mousePosInGameScreen * 0.5f + 0.5f));`?

Comment: If it's because your camera is orthographic and you need the ray to originate from the camera's position, then can't you use `Ray orthoRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(...);` `Vector3 aimPoint = orthoRay.GetPoint(aimDistance);` `Ray finalRay = new Ray(cam.transform.position, aimPoint - cam.transform.position);` `Debug.DrawRay(finalRay.origin, finalRay.direction, Color.green);`?